# Read stream from EventStore without "stream doesn't exist exception"

Tags: .net, stream, event-sourcing, eventstoredb, event-store

Application written in `.net` tries to read event stream. For this goal, EventStoreCleint wrapper was written, under the hood it uses `EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams 23.1.0`. The logic is the following:

- try to read stream
- if there is no stream (or stream version is 0) we can continue and send `TenantCreated` event
- if there is a stream (or stream version is > 0) application will not apply `TenantCreated` event.

The problem is in fact, when the application reads the event stream by `_client.ReadStreamAsync` if there is no stream, the exception will be thrown. Exceptions are expensive from the performance point of view.

How to read stream even is stream version is 0 without exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the `StreamState` in the result, it will be `StreamNotFound`

```cs
var res = await conn.ReadStreamAsync(Direction.Forwards, streamName, startPosition, Int64.MaxValue, resolveLinkTos: false, cancellationToken: ct)
if (res.ReadState == ReadState.StreamNotFound)
   // TODO handle empty
```

[Example in Equinox](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/master/src/Equinox.EventStoreDb/EventStoreDb.fs#L210)

When writing, `ConditionalAppendToStreamAsync` don't throw an exception either; you inspect the `Status` of the result.

[Example in Equinox](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/07a8d79a6d0a2aff74df2f1f1304b6f36dcedd3a/src/Equinox.EventStoreDb/EventStoreDb.fs#L130)

Comment: Just remember that checking the stream state will move the enumerable cursor by one. I personally would consider catching the exception. There must be a business rule that says the tenant does or does not exist, and if the rule is broken, you have an issue in the application (not in the model). Like, your app should have checked upfront if the tenant has been previously created.

Comment: >Just remember that checking the stream state will move the enumerable cursor by one... Are you saying this check has a side-effect? I dont believe my code triggers an exception in any case (and I'm tlaking about a lower level thing which would be used as part of an idempotent operation to insert (or do nothing if it was already inserted) - see link to my actual code

Comment: @RubenBartelink, 
The solution that you suggest, doesn't work. I tried: 

'_client.ReadStreamAsync(Direction.Forwards, name, StreamPosition.Start, long.MaxValue,false,cancellationToken:new CancellationToken())'

but still receive 'StreamNotFoundException'

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev  Thank you. 
RubenBartelink is right, we are writting an infrastructure layer, and we have IEventStore interface, and many implementations one of the implementations has EventStore under the hood. So the basic IEventStore - doesn't throw exceptions

Comment: With the TCP interface, you need to [trap WEVE from AppendToStreamAsync](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/07a8d79a6d0a2aff74df2f1f1304b6f36dcedd3a/src/Equinox.EventStore/EventStore.fs#L135). Equinox has no catch blocks when using the gRPC based interface, and absolutely loads the stream state from an empty stream before the Create operation (you can hint to it via `AssumeEmpty` to avoid the roundtrip, but it's not a default) - the tests would fail if this threw. It's possible I have some flags changed. If reading an empty stream threw, that would be stupid and a bug. But Joao didnt do that!

Comment: @Maxim are you sure you're bailing out with a check of the `ReadState` before you try to touch the events as I do? https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ajet%2Fequinox+StreamNotFound&type=code

Comment: @RubenBartelink thx. You are right. The problem was in fact we were enumerating events imidiatelly

Answer (score 0):

Key thing is to not enumerate events immediately e.g.:

> `_client.ReadStreamAsync(Direction.Forwards, name, StreamPosition.Start).ToListAsync().Result`

Instead use something like this:

```cs
var res = await _client.ReadStreamAsync(Direction.Forwards, name, StreamPosition.Start);
if (res.ReadState == ReadState.Ok)
    events = res.ToListAsync();
```